# Images in PDF files problem for ServletOutputStream

Tags: image, pdf, jsf, itext

I've searched a lot but could not solve this problem. I am generating PDF files with iText. If i use FileOutputStream everything is fine but when i try to use ServletOutputStream the images does not appear in PDF files.

When I open the PDF file with text editor, i saw that there "???" so much. That means something is shaving the bytes. It is like trying to use binary files with JSP. But i am using JSF, Tomcat 6.0, Spring 3.0 and Richfaces.

Here is the code that generates PDF with ServletOutputStream and causes problem

```
public static void saveChartToPDF(JFreeChart chart, String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Document document = new Document();
document.addCreationDate();
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos); 
document.open(); 

PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(300, 300); 
Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphics(300, 300, new DefaultFontMapper()); 

Rectangle2D r2D = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 300, 300); 
chart.draw(g2, r2D, null); 
g2.dispose(); 
cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0); 

document.close(); 

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
response.setContentLength(baos.size());

ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(out);
out.flush();
```

And here is the code works fine with FileOutputStream()

```
public static void saveChartToPDF(JFreeChart chart, String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

Document document = new Document();
document.addCreationDate();
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("c:/test1.pdf")); 

document.open(); 

PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(300, 300); 
Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphics(300, 300, new DefaultFontMapper()); 

Rectangle2D r2D = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 300, 300); 
chart.draw(g2, r2D, null); 
g2.dispose(); 
cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0); 

document.close();
```

I could not find why the bytes are being shaved.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When taking the response fully in your hands in JSF, you need to ensure that you call

```
response.reset();
```

before you set the headers, there is namely little chance that there's already something been set/written on the response (more than often by some sort of custom `Filter`).

You also need to ensure that you call

```
out.close();
```

instead of `out.flush()` to prevent that any other bytes will be written to the response body afterwards.

Finally, in JSF you need to call

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

to prevent that JSF will forward the request/response to a view (render the response).

Comment: Oh yes! It worked fine. Thanks a lot, very very appreciated. I should be more careful on closing parts.